# Exporting functions from LLVM C++ API to WebAssembly

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, webassembly, llvm-c++-api

***Situation:*** I currently parse a front-end language and generate function definitions in LLVM IR.

I can compile the function definition to a WebAssembly file using the LLVM12 C++ API.

However, the generated wasm code does not "export" any of the compiled functions and thus cannot be accessed from a javascript that loads the wasm file.

***Question:*** Could someone let me know what I might be missing? How does one tell the llvm compiler to create exports for the defined functions. I tried setting the function visibility to llvm::GlobalValue::DefaultVisibility. But that doesn't seem to help.

The generated IR for the function (with default visibility) looks like

```
define double @f(double %x) #0 {
entry:
  %multmp = fmul double %x, 2.000000e+00
  ret double %multmp
}

attributes #0 = { "target-features" }
```

The function to compile the module containing the function definition to the Wasm target looks like this:

```cpp
llvm::Module *TheModule; // module containing the function definition

// function to compile to Wasm target
bool compile_file(){
  const char *TargetTriple = "wasm-wasi";
  
  // create a llvm::Target for the specified triple
  std::string Error;
  const llvm::Target *Target =   llvm::TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(TargetTriple, Error);
  if(!Target) {
    llvm::errs() << Error;
    return false;
  }
  
  // set the options and features for the target and create a TargetMachine instance
  auto CPU = "generic";
  auto Features = "";

  llvm::TargetOptions opt;
  auto RM = llvm::Optional<llvm::Reloc::Model>();
  auto TheTargetMachine = Target->createTargetMachine(TargetTriple, CPU, Features, opt, RM);
  TheModule->setDataLayout(TheTargetMachine->createDataLayout());

  // create a output stream to write the compiled code to a .wasm file in the current directory
  std::error_code EC;
  llvm::raw_fd_ostream dest("output.wasm", EC, llvm::sys::fs::OF_None);

  if(EC) {
    llvm::errs() << "Could not open file: " << EC.message();
    return false;
  }


  // set the visibility of all functions in the module to DefaultVisibility
  auto &functionList = TheModule->getFunctionList();
  for (auto &function : functionList) {
    function.setVisibility(llvm::GlobalValue::DefaultVisibility);
  }
  
  // add a emit pass to write the generated code to the wasm file 
  llvm::legacy::PassManager pass;
  if(TheTargetMachine->addPassesToEmitFile(pass,dest,nullptr,llvm::CGFT_ObjectFile)){
    llvm::errs() << "TheTargetMachine can't emit a file of this type";
    return false;
  }
  // run the pass on the module and flush the output stream to the file
  pass.run(*(TheModule));
  dest.flush();
  // return true on success
  return true;
```

This outputs a wasm file that looks like

```
(module
  (type $t0 (func (param f64) (result f64)))
  (import "env" "__linear_memory" (memory $env.__linear_memory 0))
  (import "env" "__indirect_function_table" (table $env.__indirect_function_table 0 funcref))
  (func $f0 (type $t0) (param $p0 f64) (result f64)
    local.get $p0
    local.get $p0
    f64.add))
```

However, this generated file has a problem.
It does not add an "export" statement to make the function f0 visible to the outside world, which would allow a javascript loading the wasm module to call the function f0.
Ideally, the generated file should have the function definition line looking like

```
func $f0 (export "f") (type $t0) (param $p0 f64) (result f64)
    local.get $p0
    local.get $p0
    f64.add))
```

This way the loading javascript will have access to a function named "f" that it can call from the wasm.

Is there a way to specify to the LLVM C++ API that the function should be exported?

Comment: To set the function attribute as suggested in the answer below, one can add the attributes as follows:
function.addFnAttr( llvm::Attribute::get(TheContext,"wasm-export-name", function.getName()) ) // TheContext is the llvm::Context in which the module is defined

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can trigger the export of a given symbol by setting the `wasm-export-name` and `wasm-export-name` attributes.

In C/C++ these correspond the `export_name` and `export_module` clang attribtes.

See `llvm/test/CodeGen/WebAssembly/export-name.ll` in the llvm tree for an example of this.

You can also ask the linker to export a given symbol with the `--export` command line flag.  See https://lld.llvm.org/WebAssembly.html#exports.

Comment: Thanks @sbc100. That worked perfectly. I set the "wasm-export-name" attribute for the function using the llvm api and updated the code in a comment above, in case anyone else is wondering how this is done.

Comment: Thanks again @sbc100 . As a continuation of this work, I actually ran into another problem, where I seem to be running into a segmentation fault like situation, when running wasm files that rely on "global __stack_pointer" imports to handle struct like objects. I suspect, I am making some mistake in providing the correct type of object to be imported by __stack_pointer from my js file that loads the module. I came across your commit https://reviews.llvm.org/D34172 , and have asked for some clarification there. If that's not an appropriate place for the discussion, I'll open a new question here

Comment: Never mind. I found the answer to the __stack_pointer problem here: https://github.com/WebAssembly/tool-conventions/blob/master/DynamicLinking.md#interface-and-usage. Just needed to understand what the pointer was referring to. Giving a high enough value as an offset in the linear memory object for the stack, solves the problem.

Comment: Unless you are using the experiment PIC ABI that stack pointer should be defined within the wasm module itself and not imported.  (assuming you are actaully run wasm-ld to produce the final output?)

Comment: The import was automatically introduced by the LLVM pass generating the wasm file. I make the call to the LLVM to wasm pass using my c++ code shown in the question above (using LLVM12 C++ API). I am not sure how the API call relates to wasm-ld (I am not explicitly making any calls to wasm-ld). Also not sure what ABI the API call is using (is there a way to check/set this?)

Comment: In that case what you have is a wasm object file.   Just like a ELF object file this is not designed to be run directly, but passed to the linker (wasm-ld).   The linker will do that memory layout and set the stack pointer.